# Where to put command to disable touchpad to have it executed whenever I start PC

Tags: fedora, gnome, touchpad

I finally figured out the command to disable touchpad in my Fedora 17 using Gnome desktop 3.4.2.: `xinput set-prop 13 132 0` (specific to my Thinkpad)

Now where do I put this command, so that it is in effect every time I start the computer?
I tried putting it in ~/.xinitrc, but to no effect (the command itself works, when executed in command line, but the file is not executed automatically when I start the PC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. From terminal I started `gnome-session-properties`. This shows "Startup Application Preferences" where in the tab "Startup Programs" I added an item with  `xinput set-prop 13 132 0` as a value of "Command:" field.

For completenes - how did I find the numbers above? Using `xinput list` I found the id of my Touchpad (id=11 in my case). And using this id `xinput list-props 11` I found the option for enabling/disabling device has number 132, the value 0 meaning disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Put your command into a script, such as `DisableTouchpad.sh` then create a folder ~/.config/autostart and put the script in there

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247706/start-script-when-gnome-starts-up

Answer (score 0):

Whether `~/.xinitrc` is run will depend on your Desktop Environment, ost modern ones do not use it as they do not use `xinit`. You could try adding it to `/.xsession` or to the startup scripts in `/etc/rc5.d`

EDIT: Assuming you are always using Gnome, @Kruug's suggestion is probably better.